# Till what number do boosts stack?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

If I consume 2 painkillers, my bar is almost full and I get a decent regen.

So if I consume 10 painkillers will my regen increase 5x? or it remains the same once the bar is full?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there will be no further benefit from using any more energy drinks, pain killers or adrenaline shots, except filling up the booster bar back again to maximum. The health and speed effects are determined by the fullness of bar, not the consumed item itself and the bar cannot be filled any more than its maximum.